# How can I use jQuery to open up a new page?

Tags: jquery

I would like to use some jQuery code to:

```
a) Watch for when an element #RetrieveData is clicked
b) Get the value of #DataSource and put this into xxx
c) Open up a new page with url "/person/ds=xxx
```

I've done something similar with Ajax calls but never with calling to a new page. Can someone give me some advice as to how I can do this?

Comment: You can reuse the code where you have done this with Ajax calls - making it open a new page instead is trivial using [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#RetrieveData').click(function() {
    var xxx = $('#DataSource').val();
    window.location.href = '/person?ds=' + encodeURIComponent(xxx);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

WHen you write "new page", do you mean a new window or just page redirect?

http://jsfiddle.net/DTG7G/5/

```
$('#RetrieveData').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var xxx = $('#DataSource').val();

    //open in new window
    //window.open('/person?ds=' + encodeURIComponent(xxx));

    //open in same window
    window.location.href = '/person?ds=' + encodeURIComponent(xxx);
});
```